# Does indexedDB support foreign keys? If not, can I simulate foreign keys?

Tags: indexeddb

I'm building a web app that utilizes IndexedBD. I'm coming from a SQL background, so the concepts are different. Specifically, my understanding is that there's no real concept of a "foreign key" in indexedDB. As such, I'm trying to figure out the quickest way to retrieve a related object that, in the SQL world, would be the a foreign key.

For example, with SQL, suppose we have the following tables:

```
table carBrand:
  brandName
  brandInitial
table carModel:
  modelName
  brand (FK)
```

Now, if we have a record in `carBrand` which holds `brandName=Ford`, `brandInitial='F'` and then a record in `carModel` which holds the data `modelName = Mustang` and `brand = (FK)Ford`.

To display the `brandInitial` of this `Mustang` record in the SQL world, I could use the dot "." notation. Simply, `myCarInstance.brand.brandInitial` which would display `F`. I don't have to store to the `brandInitial` in the `carModel` record since the pointer to the foreign key holds that data.

Now moving to indexedDB, the same scenario would be set up like so:

```
objectStore "carBrand"
objectStore "carModel"
```

To have the same record (a Ford Mustang) my understanding is that we would do two `.add` calls. First, we add `brandName: "Ford"`. Next (and here's where my understanding of 'best practices' isn't solid) to add a "Ford Mustang" we would add a record to the `carModel` store which has this data:

```
modelName: "Mustang"
brand: "Ford"
```

So, with this data set up, is there a "quick" way to retrieve the record's `brandInital`? Do I have to open a transaction *just* to retrieve the `F` brand initial or is there some other approach I should use?

Answer (score 0):

In key value store like indexeddb there is no relation between objectstores. If your relationship is parent child, you can use hierarchical key, such as, [carBrand,  carModel]. See more detail about hierarchical key in appengine db api.

Comment: Yes, I realise there are no actual relationships with IndexedDB, but I was wondering if there is some easy way to follow pseudo relationships. After more research, I have gone done the path of storing objects in objects. So, instead of having relationships, I simply have nested objects. Works kind of the same, but a bit different. Now I can do the dot notation nicely.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this as well, but I decided due to the complexity of the project I was working on to go with lovefield.  There is always a tradeoff considerations to think about before adding more technology to your frontend stack, but that's another discussion altogether.